# Multithreading with SQLAlchemy ORM and in-memory SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write to an in-memory SQLite database in multiple threads. According to SQLAlchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads) this is possible. However, in practice I cannot reliably get it to work. I have tried with both `scoped_session` and without, yielding the same results. Strangely enough, if I pass `echo=True` to `create_engine` the code works every time, maybe because it forces the engine to synchronously print all statements to the screen. Code sample and exceptions are below.

EDIT: The more I look into this, the more I realize that SQLite is just not very good at concurrency for write operations. The section on [High Concurrency](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) says that while an unlimited amount of readers are allowed, there can only be one writer at any given time. A better approach here would be to queue all write operations instead of trying to achieve any level of concurrency. However I am still open to suggestions if anyone has managed to find a solution.

```
import threading
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

in_memory_engine = create_engine('sqlite://', connect_args={'check_same_thread':False}, poolclass=StaticPool)

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    data = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=in_memory_engine)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=in_memory_engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def insert_items():
    session = Session()
    for i in range(1000):
        session.add(Item(data=i))
    session.commit()
    Session.remove()

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=insert_items)
    t.start()

Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-1-e1040f59c94e>", line 26, in insert_items
    session.commit()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1027, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 494, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 473, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2459, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2597, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2557, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1138, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1253, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot start a transaction within a transaction
[SQL: INSERT INTO items (data) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: (780,)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```